# Nasm X86 multiplicación de dos variables de 8 bits (1 byte) en dos variables de 8 bits

Tags: binario, almacenamiento, x86

Hola estoy desarrollando un programa Nasm X86 multiplicación de dos variables de 8 bits (1 byte) en dos variables de 8 bits, si el resultado sobrepasa los 8 bits, se almacena el resto de los bits en la siguiente variable

Estoy usando el emulador de carlos rafael que esta en la web, por tiempo y por que no necesita tanta estructura como un compilador, y puedo ver los registro, las variables y la ejecución por pasos  sin usar el tedioso GDB de linux

```
multiplicacion:

; guarda los parámetros
mov byte ptr[0x00000402], 57
mov byte ptr[0x00000403], 100
mov al, byte ptr[0x00000402]
mov bl, byte ptr[0x00000403]

; inicializa el acarreo
mov ah, 0

; llama a la subrutina para multiplicar los bits
call multiplicacion_bits

; almacena el resultado en la memoria
mov [0x00000400], ax


; epilogue

ret

; subrutina para multiplicar los bits
multiplicacion_bits:
_loop:
; multiplica los bits
mul bl

; almacena el resultado en el acarreo
mov ah, al

; return
ret
```

el resultado me da 68 (esta bien), pero necesito que me de el resto que es 22 (los bits más significativos que no se pudieron almacenar en la primera variable[image: captura del programa])

Answer (score 0):

en vez

```
; multiplica los bits
mul bl

; almacena el resultado en el acarreo
mov ah, al

; return
ret
```

es

```
; multiplica los bits
mul bl

; almacena el resultado en el acarreo
mov bl, al

; return
ret
```

Comment: Saludos, por favor explica cómo tu propuesta soluciona el problema de OP, las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad.